# Detectar cambio de texto en un td jquery

Tags: jquery

Necesito detectar los cambios realizados en los td de mi tabla mandando un alert, saludos gracias.

```js
setTimeout(function(){
$('td[name$=total]').text("12345");
}, 3000);//hago el cambio en todos los td al pasar cierto tiempo

//busco todos los td que terminen con el nombre total
$('td[name$=total]').on(function(){

alert('el codigo ha cambiado');
});//necesito detectar el cambio en el td mandando un alert en una funcion onchange
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Codigo</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1"><!-- tabla se contruye dinamica-->
      <td name="TjnDT78BQtotal">4859</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td name="KT78df8DKtotal">2568</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
      <td name="TjnDTjgBQtotal">4859</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
      <td name="CT77gfjkKtotal">2568</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Para lograr lo que quieres simplemente debes asignar el evento [DOMSubtreeModified](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMSubtreeModified) a los `<td>` que lo requieran. Debes tener en cuenta que el evento `onchange` colo funciona para elementos de formulario (`input`, `select`, `textarea`, `checked`, etc).

Te dejo un ejemplo de código funcional:

```js
setTimeout(function(){
$('td[name$=total]').text("12345");
}, 3000);//hago el cambio en todos los td al pasar cierto tiempo

//busco todos los td que terminen con el nombre total
$('td[name$=total]').one("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
   alert('el codigo ha cambiado');
});//necesito detectar el cambio en el td mandando un alert en una funcion onchange
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Codigo</th>
      <th>Cantidad</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="1"><!-- tabla se contruye dinamica-->
      <td name="TjnDT78BQtotal">4859</td>
      <td>2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="2">
      <td name="KT78df8DKtotal">2568</td>
      <td>4</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="3">
      <td name="TjnDTjgBQtotal">4859</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="4">
      <td name="CT77gfjkKtotal">2568</td>
      <td>1</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: buen codigo pero  DOMSubtreeModified ya no es recomendable segun mozilla ellos recomiendan usar : MutationObserver https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver